# Redirection www to non-www in AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I want to redirect www to non-www traffic. I have updated the .htaccess file but it doesn't work.

Coding used:
RewriteEngine Enabled
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

It seems that changes to the .htaccess in Apache are handled differently... And the edits are not applied.

Could you advise me how to handle the www to non-www redirection?

I have a duplicate website the www. and the nacked version. I would like to redirect all traffic to nacked link.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami instances are always tricky. They have moved some system configuration files to /opt/bitnami from /etc.

The Apache vhosts configuration files sits at: `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts`

Add your rewrite rules to `wordpress-vhost.conf` and `wordpress-https-vhost.conf`. Then restart Apache with `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`.

Here is how my wordpress-https-vhost.conf looks like:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
  ServerAlias *
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key"
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/wordpress
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/wordpress">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    # Redirect www to non-www
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    # BEGIN WordPress fix for plugins and themes
    # Certain WordPress plugins and themes do not properly link to PHP files because of symbolic links
    # https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress-nginx/issues/43
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^bitnami/wordpress(/.*) $1 [L]
    # END WordPress fix for plugins and themes
    # BEGIN WordPress
    # https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/#basic-wp
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WordPress
  </Directory>
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/htaccess/wordpress-htaccess.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```